# Linux partition mountpoint

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount

I checked the partitions on my linux system this morning and `lsblk` shows a strange mountpoint for the main partition `mvne0n1p6`:

```
$ lsblk /dev/nvme0n1
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1     259:0    0 476,9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   300M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   128M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0  93,2G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0   900M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0  21,6G  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p6 259:6    0 360,9G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                      /
```

My system boots well. I don't understand why that mountpoint `/var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell` instead of `/` and why several mountpoints ?

Here is the `/etc/fstab` :

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p6 during installation
UUID=b5ade8db-3621-455e-81d0-ceb8741b53c8 /            ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=D08E-25EA                            /boot/efi    vfat    umask=0077        0       1
/swapfile
```

It mentions that only `/` was on `/dev/nvme0n1p6` during installation.

Here are the distro and kernel versions:

```
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
$ uname -srm
Linux 5.19.0-50-generic x86_64
```

Could you help me to understand that strange mountpoint ? Is it possible to remove it and how ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the subject of the post
[lsblk: root partition mounted on / and /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1431815/lsblk-root-partition-mounted-on-and-var-snap-firefox-common-host-hunspell)

An [answer by vanadium](https://askubuntu.com/a/1432752/963426) says this:

> As [indicated](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/sdb5-mounted-on-firefox/31897) over at the snapcraft forum, this mount is set up to
> allow Firefox Snap to use the spell check dictionaries (hunspell) of
> the main system. A discussion about this commit is available
> [here](https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/pull/11025).

The accepted
[answer by Liyong Zhou](https://askubuntu.com/a/1446845/963426)
says :

> Below command removes the extra binding instantly:
>
> ```
> snap disconnect firefox:host-hunspell
> ```
>
> The dual binding is not harmful nor a bug, but looks un-linux to me.

This binding can simply be ignored, if it's not too bothersome.

Comment: Good explanation. Thanks a lot !